# Largest integer solution to $2^{\pi-x}\cos{\pi x}=(-1)^{x+10}\cdot 4^{x+\frac{\pi}{2}-3}$

Tags: calculus

$$2^{\pi-x}\cos{\pi x}=(-1)^{x+10}\cdot 4^{x+\frac{\pi}{2}-3}$$
By simply looking at the equation one can draw a few conclusions.

1. $RHS>0 \quad \forall x\in\mathbb{R}$, which implies that we're looking for $x\in\mathbb{N}.$
2. Since $2^{\pi-x}$, I can divide both sides by it and obtain (knowing that $(-1)^{10}=1$) $$\cos{\pi x}=(-1)^{x}\cdot2^{3x-6}.$$

I know that the function $f(\theta)=\cos{\theta}$ is positive in $0\leq\theta<\frac{\pi}{2}$ and in $\frac{3\pi}{2}<\theta\leq2\pi$. This means that $$0\leq x<\frac{1}{2} \quad \text{or} \quad \frac{3}{2}<x\leq2$$

So the only solution $x\in\mathbb{N}$ that lies within our constraints for $x$ is $x=2.$

Any better/faster method? Can I improve anything in my solution?

Comment: $x$ is integer because for any $x$ LHS is real, while RHS is real only for integer $x$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After re-reading your solution, I don't understand a step you make (and it is actually wrong).

You are correct up to the equation $$\cos \pi x = (-1)^x2^{3x-6}$$ but then, you conclude from this that

> I know that the function $f(\theta)=\cos{\theta}$ is positive in $0<\theta<\frac{\pi}{2}$ and in $\frac{3\pi}{2}<\theta<2\pi$. This means that $$0<x<\frac{1}{2} \quad \text{or} \quad \frac{3}{2}<x<2$$

but I see no reason why your conclusion would follow from the assumptions. The function is **also** positive on $-2\pi < \theta<-\frac{3\pi}{2}$, for example!

---

Instead, if I were you, I would, use the fact that $\cos \pi x=1$ for all even values of $x$ and $-1$ for all odd values of $x$, and split the cases.

---

1. If $x$ is odd, then the equation becomes $-1 = (-1)\cdot 2^{3x-6}$ which simplifies to $2^{3x-6}=1$ which is only possible if $3x-6=0$ or $x=2$, an impossible solution since $x$ should be odd. So, there is no solution with odd $x$.
2. If $x$ is even, then the equation becomes $1=1\cdot 2^{3x-6}$, and I trust you know how to continue from here.

Comment: Well, it follows because in my case $\theta=\pi x$, and dividing both $\theta$-inequalities with $\pi$, I get the inequalities in the yellow box. But the insight about odd and even $x$:es was great, i feel stupid thatI did not see it myself. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Parseval Yeah, sure, the second pair of inequalities follows from the first, but you miss out on the inequalities such as $-2\pi<\theta<\frac{-3\pi}{2}$ (and infinitely other sets of equations).

Comment: Yes you're right, but that problem is solved by just adding on $2\pi k$ for any integer $k$.

Comment: @Parseval Come to think of it, your main mistake was focusing on $\cos\theta>0$, which has nothing to do with the solution (since both sides of the equation can be positive *or* negative).

Comment: True. I did not think about that $(-1)^x$ is negative for odd x:es.

Answer (score 3):

For $x \ \in \ \mathbb{N}$, $\cos (\pi x) = (-1)^x$

$\implies 2^{\pi -x} = 4^{x + \frac{\pi}{2} - 3}$

$\implies  2^{\pi -x} = 2^{2x + \pi - 6}$

$\implies x =2$

Comment: This is cool. So one can actually divide both sides with $\cos(\pi x)$ or $(-1)^x$ WLOG since $\cos{\pi x}=(-1)^x\neq 0, \quad \forall x\in\mathbb{N}.$